# How to handle messages from another process so that they are sent on an Elixir Phoenix channel

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, phoenix-channels

I have channels working perfectly based on the [docs](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/channels.html#incoming-events), and my application is receiving and re-broadcasting messages as expected:

[image]

Here's the code that handles the channel:

```
defmodule HelloWeb.RoomChannel do
  use Phoenix.Channel

  def join("room:lobby", _message, socket) do
    {:ok, socket}
  end
  def join("room:" <> _private_room_id, _params, _socket) do
    {:error, %{reason: "unauthorized"}}
  end

  def handle_in("new_msg", %{"body" => body}, socket) do
    broadcast!(socket, "new_msg", %{body: body})
    {:noreply, socket}
  end
end
```

However what I *really* want is to send messages down this Phoenix channel that come from a different Elixir process (which happens to be subscribed to a third party API via websockets). So whenever I get a websocket message from the third party handler process, I want to send that message to this `RoomChannel` module, and get it to send the message down the channel to the browser.

How do I do this? Is there a GenServer-style `handle_info` handler that I can write that will listen for incoming messages within `RoomChannel` and send it down the Phoenix channel?

Or do I somehow have to send the Phoenix socket to another GenServer to handle it there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Phoenix.Channel` is not a `GenServer` on its own, it uses [`Phoenix.Channel.Server`](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/v1.5.8/lib/phoenix/channel.ex#L430-L434) underneath, but it mimics the `GenServer` behaviour. This is not shown in the main tutorial documentation but you can find it if you look through the reference:

[`Phoenix.Channel.handle_info/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Channel.html#c:handle_info/2).